# How do I undo the last Add-Migration command?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I have created a migration using the `Add-Migration` command, but I'd like to change the name of that migration. How can I undo the migration command, so that I can regenerate it using the new desired name?

Is it just a matter of deleting the generated files, or this could be a bad idea?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

If you haven't used `Update-Database` you can just delete the migration file. If you've run the update you should roll it back using `Update-Database -TargetMigration "NameOfPreviousMigration"` then delete the migration file.

Reference:

http://elegantcode.com/2012/04/12/entity-framework-migrations-tips/

Comment: what if it was the first migration added?

Comment: @Jimmyt1988, use Update-Database –TargetMigration: $InitialDatabase

Comment: Then delete it? I don't get it. Then delete what?

Comment: @tnk479 the migration file. Edited to make it clearer

Comment: Sad to see that older version of EF (Like EF 6) doesn't have `drop-database` and `remove-migration` commands

Answer (score 17):

If you haven't executed the migration yet with `Update-Database`, you can run `Add-Migration` again with the same name (you may need to use `-Force`) to re-execute the scaffolding. This is noted in the output of the `Add-Migration` command.

Comment: This is not a good solution as this will not restore ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot

Comment: @Trojaner you are right, so the response https://stackoverflow.com/a/46921867/690958 is the better solution

Comment: Can it also clean up the files?
For me it leaves the migration file, but with empty Up() and Down() methods.

Comment: But the question is not about EF-Core, I find this answer working well with pre-core EF. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Steve correct. The question and answer are dated 2014, .NET Core had its first release in 2016.

Answer (score 13):

Just use command

```
Remove-migration
```

It will remove last added migration and update snapshot. It will not affect database so you have to rollback db in first place.

Comment: Only in EF Core.

Comment: I wish it would be there in EF 6 along with `drop-database` commands.. I am too used to it

Answer (score 6):

To add to @Ben 's answer, when using the `dotnet ef` command variety this is the remove command you need:

`dotnet ef migrations remove`

Which will remove your last migration and update the model snapshot.

Answer (score 4):

With EntityFrameworkCore 2.0 comes the model snapshot. You will need to run the remove migration command in order to update the model snapshot. I have read that EF Core will recognize any update and revert the snapshot for you if you manually delete the migration but this has not worked for me.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-migrations-remove

Answer (score 3):

Update your last perfect migration via this command :

```
Update-Database –TargetMigration
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use command:

```
Update-Database nameMigration -context nameContext
```

And Then

```
Remove-migration -Context nameContext
```

Answer (score 0):

If you work with EF on daily basis, you might find [efmig](https://github.com/stil/efmig) tool useful.

It's two clicks:

1. "Remove from code" - this action will remove code of your latest migration from codebase. However, if you have already applied it to the database, you should do "Generate rollback script" and manually apply generated SQL first.
2. You create a new migration with desired name.

[image: efmig main window]

Disclaimer: I'm the author, the project is open source and I've been using it at my daily work for long time now.