# Delete table from EF CodeFirst migration

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

In EF Code first, I want to drop one column from one table & then delete another  table.

After removing one column from class file, automatically one migration file generated.

But how to delete table.

what command need to fire? Do I need to delete complete class file & also remove following line from Context file?

```
 public DbSet<TableClassName> TableClassNameSet { get; set; }
```

I use, Add Migration 'TableClassName' command.

So what is best way to remove table?

Answer (score 16):

If you just made the changes in the last migration, you can [rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21312103/how-do-i-undo-the-last-add-migration-command) that migration. Otherwise, just adjust your models and the changes will be picked up in the next migration. To remove a table, simply remove the corresponding `DbSet<MyClass>` and any references to that class in other parts of your model and EF will add a DropTable to the migration automatically. If you are no longer using the class for non-Entity Framework purposes you can delete it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, for me that's what solved it, I removed any reference in the project of the entity class that I needed to delete, and on generating the DropTable add-migration, the ef generated the DropTable in the UP method.

Answer (score 6):

1. Delete from your context class this line

   public DbSet TableClassNameSet { get; set; }
2. Execute this command:

   Update-DataBase -force -verbose

Answer (score 5):

To drop a table, you can use `DropTable("YourTable")` in the `Up()` method of your `DBMigration` class.

Also take a look at the following link for more examples on how to customize the migration.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/jj591621.aspx#customizing

Comment: Using DropTable is correct but it's probably better to adjust the model.

Also the question seems to be about deleting a table not undoing a migration. Down() is for reversing the latest migration. So from my understanding the code should be in the Up() in this case.

Comment: @MikaelEliasson Yes, Thanks. Done :)