# How to undo Entity Framework Update-Database in .NET Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core

In the standard .NET version of entity framework, you could [undo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21312606/852806) the last database update using.

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration "NameOfPreviousMigration"
```

If you try this on Entity Framework for .NET Core (EntityFrameworkCore), you get the following error:

> Update-Database : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter
>   name 'TargetMigration'. At line:1 char:17
>   + Update-database -TargetMigration "NameOfPreviousMigration"
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Update-Database], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Update-Database

How can I revert the database in .NET Core?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To do this in EntityFrameworkCore, you don't use the TargetMigration parameter. Just name the migration you wish to revert to.

e.g.

```
Update-Database NameOfPreviousMigration
```