# Entity Framework 6 Code first update Entity with oracle

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, migration, code-first

Migration data first time success. 
But when I update entity and migration again, it fails:

> Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following
>   explicit migrations are pending: [201712281248174_ttt]. Apply the
>   pending explicit migrations before attempting to generate a new
>   explicit migration.

Help! Thank you!

Comment: Try [these suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817860/unable-to-generate-an-explicit-migration-in-entity-framework) first and report back if your scenario is different along with relevant code and things you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable automatic migrations in your migration configuration file.

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
}
```

or explicitly run command `Update-Database` in Package Manager Console.

Comment: Thank you! I find the problem is the HasDefaultSchema parameter difference with the User Id in connectionStrings.