# Migrations pending when adding new migration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Whilst trying to add migration the error shows up:

```
Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending: 
[202105121227574_InitialModel, 202105130939495_AddIsSubscribedToCustomer, 
202105130949458_AddMembershipType, 202105130952550_PopulateMembershipTypes, 
202105131009495_ApplyAnnotationsToCustomerName, 202105131435142_AddNameToMembershipType,  
02105131435496_UpdateExistingMembership, 202105131443052_UpdateExistingMembership2,...
```

Which doesn't make much sense as long time ago I've added them and updated database after each one.
So I tried to update-database, but as one might suspect the error "There is already an object named 'ColumnName' in the database." shows up.

Comment: Hi, could you please add the error message inside a quotation brackets, for a better reading experience. Thank you :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to generate an explicit migration in entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817860/unable-to-generate-an-explicit-migration-in-entity-framework)

Answer (score 1):

As M.D. pointed out, the answer is probably here in [Unable to generate an explicit migration in entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817860/unable-to-generate-an-explicit-migration-in-entity-framework).

However if this option is option is available to you. drop the db, delete the migration folder and then re-run Add-Migration & Update-database on your package manager console

You can also try run Update-database to apply pending changes.